# Column present in Database but not in Hibernate mapping xml

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a use case where one field is present in Table but not present in the `Hibernate hbm xml`

and POJO. Will it cause any issues while compilation or running or persisting?

Comment: No it should cause any issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not cause any issue. Otherwise it will become the worst ORM.